# Android studio gets stuck when updating SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, updating, android-studio-2.0

It doesn't go past this:
[image]

Tried twice. Any ideeas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrated sdk manager is still not 100% reliable. Try to download it using the standalone sdk manager.

Comment: Thanks, trying it now

Answer (score 1):

Now when Standalone SDK GUI is deprecated/deleted it's quite tricky to do it via command line. I've found another solution (for my problem) - delete problematic component through Android Studio SDK and install it again through Android Studio SDK.

This trick helps in my case which was problem with patching Google's API system image file system.img for Android 7.1 from revision 10 to 11 (patching stuck on that file)